# Probability of sequence of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question** : Let ${A_n}$ be a sequence of events with P($A_n$)=1 $\forall n$ $\geq$1. Find P($\cup A_n$ ) and P($\cap A_n $)

---

**What I did**:
  Since it is given that P($A_n$)=$1$ we can easily say that all $A_n$ are sure events for all n $\geq 1$.So as all are sure events so each $A_n$ contains every other events so basically,
 we can think $\cup A_n$ as $A_k$ for any k $\in {1,2,....n}$ thus
P( $\cup A_n$ )=P( $A_k$)=$1$

Similarly for ( $\cap A_n $) we get it as $ 1$.

---

Am I doing any mistake ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The method used for union will not work for intersection.

Comment: As far as I can tell, $A_n$ happens [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely). It makes the interesection case non-trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea for union is okay and is an application of the monotonicity of measures:

$A_{1}\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ so that $P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)\geq P\left(A_{1}\right)=1$.

For intersection you did the same...? (I really wonder what that is here)

This can be solved like this:

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}=\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}^{\complement}\right)^{\complement}$
so that: $$P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)=1-P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}^{\complement}\right)\geq1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(A_{n}^{\complement}\right)=1$$

Comment: by same what i mean is ...as all A_n contain the all the  other so we can say that on taking intersection it will give me A_k for k belongs to 1,2....n so probability of events on taking intersection will be same   as any one event say, A_k

Comment: But it is not guaranteed that $A_k\subseteq\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ for any $k$. On the contrary I would say. What we do have is $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\subseteq A_k$ for every $k$ and that only tells us that $P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)\leq P(A_k)=1$ so is not really useful.

Answer (score 4):

- For the first part: $P(\bigcup_{n \ge 1} A_n) \ge P(A_1)$
- For the second part: $P(\bigcap_{n \ge 1} A_n) = 1-P(\bigcup_{n\ge 1} A_n^c) = 1-0$. (You may need to prove that the countable union of zero-probability events has zero probability.)

Answer (score 1):

You need a proof for the intersection. Correct proof:
 $1\geq P(\cup_n A_n )\geq P(A_1)=1$ so $P(\cup_n A_n )=1$. Now $P(A_n^{c})=0$ for all $n$ so $0\leq P(\cup_n A_n^{c}) \leq \sum P(A_n^{c})=\sum 0=0$ so $P((\cup_n A_n^{c})=0$. This implies that $P(\cap_n A_n)=1$.